# How does this program manage to allocate so much memory?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

I was curious to understand how much memory can I allocate on my laptop, therefore I ran the minimalist program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int Gb = 0;
    while ( malloc(1<<30) ){
            ++Gb;
            printf("Now allocated %d Gb in total\n", Gb);
    }
}
```

It should allocate 1Gb of memory at every step, until the malloc fails (NULL), ending the loop.
On the other hand, the output that I obtain ends with:

> Now allocated 131063 Gb in total

and it cannot definitely be true (I have 8Gb of RAM and no swap partition).
Can I ask, what am I misunderstanding?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, I am working with Linux.

Comment: only allocation is not sufficient, you need to use the memory too, in order to avoid kernel tricking you in believing that you actually have the memory.

Comment: "Memory overcommitment" is your search term. In fact it can be turned off.

Comment: @EugeneSh. out of curiosity: is there a quick way to turn it off, just for the sake of experimenting?

Comment: @max2 Take a look here https://engineering.pivotal.io/post/virtual_memory_settings_in_linux_-_the_problem_with_overcommit/ But it might vary from Linux to Linux I imagine

Comment: @EugeneSh. the linked article is FANTASTIC! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wonders of virtual memory. Until you actually initialize it somehow, memory doesn't need to take up any RAM. You'll get a far different result from

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned num_blocks = 0;
    for (char *p; ( p = malloc(1<<30) ); ) {
       memset(p, 0, 1<<30);  // <-----
       ++num_blocks;
       printf("Now allocated %u GiB in total\n", num_blocks);
    }
}
```

Allocating more more virtual memory than the machine has physical memory is known as [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment).

There's some interesting information found in the article [Virtual memory settings in Linux - The Problem with Overcommit](https://engineering.pivotal.io/post/virtual_memory_settings_in_linux_-_the_problem_with_overcommit/).

Comment: And so, it is also a good way to find (approximately) how much virtual memory your CPU (and kernel) could support. Warning: page indices takes also memory, so you may get problems earlier.

Comment: So what is the point of checking the return value from `malloc` if it is "allocating" memory that you can't actually use, but will cause a segfault when accessed later?

Comment: I've often wondered, does calloc require the memory to be there, or might the system wait till you used it?

Comment: This is very interesting to know: I had the idea that to activate memory virtualization, the use of a swap partition - which I don't have - was mandatory. Thanks for the explanation! For completeness, I run your code, but the results are still the same.

Comment: Makes me wonder then, if even though it is slower, using `calloc` in this example would be a better choice. (it internally initializes all memory locations.)

Comment: @max2 Probably because I touched only touched only one of the pages, not all of the pages of the block. (And I presume you got exactly the same result because that page was probably already touched because of some info block at the start of the allocated block.) As suggested, using `calloc` or otherwise touching more of the memory will do it. Adjusted answer. I don't dare test this program on my system.

Comment: This would not make much difference, because on common systems only one page per allocation has to be allocated physically (e.g. 4096 bytes per allocated GB). You had to use `bzero(p, 1<<30)` (or touch at least one byte _per page_) to see a significant difference

Comment: @WeatherVane This will not result in a segfault on a sane system, but the OOM killer will terminate the process

Comment: While I like your answer, this doesn't actually answer the question in an accurate manner. You should at least take care of "*It should allocate 1Gb of memory at every step, until the malloc fails (NULL), ending the loop.*". Emphasis lies on "*until malloc fails(NULL), ending the loop*".

Comment: The new example works well, thanks! (to be 100% precise, I had to add <string.h>, I say just in case someone else was interested in directly copy and paste the code).

Comment: @Ctx isn't that almost as bad? I've just been reading C17 about `malloc`, and there is no mention of circumstances where `malloc` is allowed to lie. Is this conforming behaviour?

Comment: @WeatherVane It depends on which scope you apply for the standard. It certainly is not good to have a sane program killed because of such mechanisms. Otoh, it can be compared a bit with a power failure. The big advantage of memory overcommittment is, that you can adjust the scoring a bit to define, which processes are crucial and which are not, so the oom killer can free resources for more important processes. The best in an ideal world is of course to have enough memory without overcommitment.

Comment: I'd like to clarify a point: what would have happened if I ran my code on another system, say an obsolete MS-DOS? I would obtain the correct results with the very first example, right? In other words, we are not talking about a feature of modern C itself, rather of the underlying system on which the code is executed. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Ctx if it is non-conforming behaviour shouldn't there be a non-standard function to check if the promised memory is actually available (or to "reserve the memory" to prevent a race condition), before accessing it and being summarily killed in some way?

Comment: @max2, MS-DOS did not support virtual memory. It could only allocate actual RAM

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed it is possible, you can use `mlockall()` to lock all virtual pages of the calling process to physical memory (POSIX'ism)

Comment: @Weather Vane, It's not lying. It's indeed allocating memory: reserving a range of addresses in the memory space. Or does the spec require it to do more than that?

Comment: I must have thought that `malloc` *guarantees* the memory can be used if it does not return `NULL`. I can understand the use if different processes all want the whole of physical memory, and the system will take care of swapping, but otherwise I would implement a random-access file myself.

Comment: Thanks to @Engene Sh. for both links in my answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane: you can configure the OOM killer not to overcommit memory (which it is the correct way, according standards). OTOH it was shown that programs often overcommit and never use all the memory. And there are already other kind of overcommit, e.g. then you clone/fork your program: you will not overcommit all memory (originally it was just a copy, now just a reference, but you may use all the copy), and 99% of cases after fork there is a exec (so releasing all memory)